# error: failed to write, failed to open stream, pecl install oauth on mac osx el capitan

Tags: php, macos, oauth, pecl

I'm trying to install OAuth version 1.2.3 locally with pecl install (running PHP 5.6.10 on Mac OSX El Capitan). Running the following in command prompt:

```
sudo pecl install oauth-1.2.3
```

Installation starts fine and runs without errors up until build is done. Then I get this error:

```
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/oauth.so'
ERROR: failed to write /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-`20121212/oauth.so 
(copy(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/oauth.so): 
failed to open stream: Operation not permitted)`
```

ls shows no oauth.so in folder no-debug-non-zts-20121212, but other than that, folder looks fine.

Things I've tried:
- updating pear and pecl
- updating MAMP
- restarting webserver
- restarting computer

Am running out of ideas of things to try. Anyone who's heard of this issue before?

Answer (score 13):

You need to disable the System Integrity Protection.

1. Reboot the Mac and hold down <kbd>Command + R</kbd> keys simultaneously after you hear the startup chime, this will boot OS X into Recovery Mode.
2. When the "OS X Utilities" screen appears, pull down the "Utilities" menu at the top of the screen, and choose "Terminal".
3. Type the following command into the terminal then hit return:
   `csrutil disable`
4. You’ll see a message saying that System Integrity Protection has been disabled and the Mac needs to restart for changes to take effect.
5. Enter the `reboot` command, and the Mac will then reboot itself automatically, just let it boot up as normal.

Then try again with `sudo pecl install oauth-1.2.3`. After the **oauth.so** is correctly installed in **/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/** you should enable the SIP again (after all, this is a feature to protect our system, so it's better to keep it ON).

References consulted:

- [Install mcrypt for php on Mac OSX 10.11 El Capitan for a Development Server](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-mcrypt-for-php-on-mac-osx-10-10-yosemite-for-a-development-server/).
- [How to Disable System Integrity Protection (rootless) in OS X El Capitan](http://osxdaily.com/2015/10/05/disable-rootless-system-integrity-protection-mac-os-x/).

Answer (score 0):

**Enabling/Disabling** System Integrity Protection is a headache... Instead, follow this link and change your PHP directory path.

http://mrgott.com/misc/10-install-mcrypt-and-intl-php-extensions-on-mac-os-x-and-xampp

Comment: Can you include the text from the link? that link is dead