# failed to open stream: Read-only file system on Mac Big Sur

Tags: php, macos, pecl, macos-big-sur, php-mongodb

I'm trying to install mongo at my mac, I run "pecl install mongodb" and got

```
ERROR: failed to write /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/mongodb.so (copy(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/mongodb.so): failed to open stream: Read-only file system)
```

then I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34850904/error-failed-to-write-failed-to-open-stream-pecl-install-oauth-on-mac-osx-el) , but i still get the same error message said failed to open stream .

I've tried `sudo mount -uw /`  and get `mount_apfs: volume could not be mounted: Permission denied mount: / failed with 66`

But I check my csrutil status. It shows `System Integrity Protection status: disabled.`

How to make it writeable.